# Drupal theme recommendation (Bootstrap 3 + megamenu)

Tags: templating, drupal, bootstrap

Looking for a **free** Drupal theme with the following features:

- based on Bootstrap 3
- has implemented as *shortcodes* all (most) of features what Bootstrap 3 has, e.g:

  - tabs
  - accordions
  - buttons, wells
  - paging, breadcrumbs
  - font-awesome icons
  - styled tables
  - etc.
  - scrollspy & affixed sidebar (would be nice)
- and **plus**, has implemented additional component for *mega-menus*

(Asking here, because themes for Drupal contain PHP, e.g. "software", and unfortunately theme recommendations on Drupal Stack Exchange are forbidden and searching drupal.org for themes isn't easy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the contributed theme [Bootstrap Business](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_business), which is a sub-theme of the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme. It should fit quite a few of your requirements.

Some months ago I did some type of comparison of various bootstrap subthemes, and this subtheme turned out to be the best alternative available.

If it doesn't entirely fit your requirements, I suggest you have a look at the [Drupal Bootstrap Documentation](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap) and use it to create your own custom subtheme, starting from  the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme as your base theme.

Comment: I abandoned Drupal - so can't check-verify the answer. So, accepting it blindly - thank you.